# Number guessing game that forces the user to make the maximum amount of guesses (Java)

Tags: java

This program, when played by a user, will seem to act just like the original program (in fact, someone playing the two games should not be able to tell them apart).
*In the original program, the user guesses at a random number between 1 and 100. After every guess, the program returns whether the number was higher or lower than the guess until the user guesses correctly.*

However, this program cheats. Rather than selecting a random number in the range 1-100, your program does not think of a hidden number at all, but instead answers 
in such a way as to force the user to make as many guesses as possible.

How can I make this happen? do I need to do a for loop of if else statements or something? The only thing that I can think to do right now is make a crap ton of if else, and I don't even know if that will work.

Should I continue with this inner if else idea, but getting more and more specific? I just feel like there must be a better way.

**UPDATE***

Okay so I think I've figured out what I originally came for, but now the program gets stuck in an infinite loop when I choose a number with equal upper and lower options for guessing. Any idea why?

```
    public static int feedback (Scanner console, int guess, int max) {
        String sorry = "Sorry, that guess is incorrect.";
        String lower = "The number I am thinking of is lower.";
        String higher = "The number I am thinking of is higher.";   
        int guessCount = 0;
        guess = console.nextInt();
        int upperBound = max + 1;
        int lowerBound = 0;
        if (guess <= max && guess >= 1) {
            guessCount = guessCount + 1;
             if (max - guess < guess) { 
                    System.out.println(sorry);
                    System.out.println(lower);
                    System.out.print("Your guess? ");
                    upperBound = guess;
                    guess = console.nextInt();
                    guessCount = guessCount + 1;
             } else {
                    System.out.println(sorry);
                    System.out.println(higher);
                    System.out.print("Your guess? ");
                    lowerBound = guess;
                    guess = console.nextInt();
                    guessCount = guessCount + 1;

             while (upperBound - lowerBound > 2) {
                 if (guess <= max && guess >= 1) {
                     if ((lowerBound + ((upperBound - lowerBound)/2)) < guess) { 
                         System.out.println(sorry);
                         System.out.println(lower);
                         System.out.print("Your guess? ");
                         upperBound = guess;
                         guess = console.nextInt(); 
                         guessCount = guessCount + 1;
                     } else {
                            System.out.println(sorry);
                            System.out.println(higher);
                            System.out.print("Your guess? ");
                            lowerBound = guess;
                            guess = console.nextInt();
                            guessCount = guessCount + 1;
                            }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your guess must be in the range 1-" + max + ". Try again.");
                }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Yes, the number I was thinking of was " + guess);
                }
             } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess must be in the range 1-" + max + ". Try again.");
            return guessCount;
        }
        return guessCount;
        }
```

Comment: Start with the crapton!

Comment: Think of the constraints: any new answer should not contradict a past answer. The range left for the user to guess from, should be maximal. However, against a user using binary search, cheating will at most force him to do log2(n) guesses.

Comment: You are kind of on the right track here.  But keep in mind that the available range of numbers keeps changing.  If the user guesses 90 and your program says "lower", then 89 is the new highest possible number; 90 through 100 are now ruled out.  Likewise if the user guesses 20 and the program says "higher" then 21 is the new lowest possible number.  You need to keep track of the lowest and highest possible numbers, and each guess will change one of those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Each guess partitions the available range of numbers.

Before the first guess, the number could be anything from 1 to 100.  Suppose the user guesses "60".  This gives us three possibilities: less than 60, equal to 60, or greater than 60.

Now you need to decide which one of those three possibilities will keep the user guessing the longest.  I'll give you a hint: you don't want to say the user is correct until there is only one number left for the user to guess, so definitely don't accept "60" as a first guess.

You should be able to write a loop that accepts an input, then decides how to answer based on the input.  For example, if the user's first guess is "99", you definitely want your program to say "too large".  Have the loop keep running until there is only one answer left.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: No, I get the idea of choosing the range with more possibilities, I just need help converting that to code! I feel like the only way to do it would be tedious, repetitive and take forever, and I can't wrap my head around that. I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Start with some variables to define your current ranges i.e

```
int lower = 1;
int upper = 100;
```

Create a method which takes the guess of the user. This method should determine which of the range bounds to replace based on how the guess would divide the range i.e the bound it is closest to (as keeping your range as large as possible for as long as possible is the goal). Then it should return (or print) higher or lower then loop back to getting another guess from the user

```
// For example
Starts  lower = 1, upper = 100
User guesses 25
Replace lower with 25
say to guess higher
Get another guess  range is now lower = 25, upper = 100
User guesses 75
replace upper with 75
say to guess lower
get another guess  range is now lower = 25, upper = 75
etc, etc, etc, until guess has to be correct.
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to allow for any guess, at any point. Even when it can only be 25-75, the program needs to be able to respond to a guess of 97.

Comment: Well in that case you just don't replace the bound as the user is obviously a retard